# How to use a variable string with array in a foreach loop

Tags: php, xml, loops

I try to get the following code working.

```php
foreach ($uniqueItems as $key => $value) {
 $output = "{$value->properties->property[10]->value}";
 echo $output;
}
```

In the browser I see 24.99

Above code gives me the correct output. But I need the $output from outside this foreach. I try the following

```php
$output = "{\$value->properties->property[10]->value}";
foreach ($uniqueItems as $key => $value) {
 echo $output;
}
```

In the browser I see {$value->properties->property[10]->value}

This is print_r($uniqueItems[$key]);

```xml
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [name] => Donnay joggingbroek zwart unisex
    [properties] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [property] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => deliveryTime
                                )

                            [value] => Voor 16.00 uur besteld, morgen in huis!
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => brand
                                )

                            [value] => Donnay
                        )

                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => size
                                )

                            [value] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => color
                                )

                            [value] => Zwart
                        )

                    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => EAN
                                )

                            [value] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => categoryPath
                                )

                            [value] => Tenniskleding/Tenniskleding dames
                        )

                    [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => deliveryCosts
                                )

                            [value] => 4.95
                        )

                    [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => discount
                                )

                            [value] => 5.00
                        )

                    [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => subcategories
                                )

                            [value] => Tenniskleding dames
                        )

                    [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => SKU
                                )

                            [value] => 489000-TL-020
                        )

                    [10] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => fromPrice
                                )

                            [value] => 24.99
                        )
))
```

How to get the right output?

Comment: `But I need the $output from outside this foreach.` What does this mean? You mean you want to concat it with an existing string? E.g. `$output .= ....`? Your second code snippet doesn't make sense.

Comment: The $output is coming from a db.

Comment: You are not trying to create your own json string?

Comment: $uniqueItems is a simplexml_load_file($xmlfile)

Answer (score 0):

The second snippet won't work as php does not know that `$value` is to be interpolated until `$value` gets defined which is happening when the loop actually starts. Till then, it will just be a string. That's why it's just printing out it as a string

Comment: You can use the below answer by Alive to Die to access the data.

Comment: But if you really want to keep the way you access the data outside your loop, you can consider using variable variables.https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: So I create this.
`$output = array('properties','property',10,'value');
  $p1 = $output[0];
  $p2 = $output[1];
  $p3 = $output[2];
  $p4 = $output[3];
  foreach ($uniqueItems as $key => $value) {
    $output = $value->$p1->$p2[$p3]->$p4;
    echo $output;
  }`
But now it will not work when i get $output = array(name);

Comment: @MarcelKroeze  please add proper explanation of your problem +correct input data+your real code what you have tried+your expected result by editing your question otherwise no one can help you.